# Chrome Mobile Android Add to Homescreen fullscreen

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Today I discovered that I can make a page like a native app with shortcut on the homescreen, opens almost full screen ... I did a test and it worked, now I need to make it work 100% fullscreen, hiding the top bar and down on Android 4.3 and 4.4, is it possible?

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.3 and 4.4 come with Chrome for Android by default, so Yes.

If you are asking if you can do this with the Stock Android browser which is on non-Google Android phones and phones that have upgraded from an earlier Android version, the answer is no not quite.

Android Browser does allow you to window.scrollTo(0,1) which will hide the navigation bar (but it will be visible if the user scrolls)